# divisibility of central binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Every central binomial coefficient, starting with the one in row 2, is divisible by two. There are a few proofs of this already on this site, like 
[prove that $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ is even if $n$ is a positive integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/78533/prove-that-frac2nn2-is-even-if-n-is-a-positive-integer)

I looked at Pascal's triangle, and every other central binomial coefficient starting at the one in row 6, appears to be divisible by four. Is this true? Is there a nice way to prove this? (I attempted to use Pascal's identity, but didn't arrive to anything).

Side Note: 
It also looks like every 4th central binomial coefficient, starting at row 14, is divisible by 8. Is it a pattern that doubling the previous "starting row" and adding two gives the next "starting row", and doubling the previous "gap" gives the new gap for the next power of two? I checked a few things: central binomial coefficient in row 30 is divisible by 16, the central coefficient in row 62 is divisible by 32, and the one in row 126 is divisible by 64.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer%27s_theorem

Comment: Tangentially related: [when is $\binom{2n}{n}\frac{1}{2n}$ an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700613/when-is-binom2nn-cdot-frac12n-an-integer)