# Divisibility of a binomial coefficient - an exception?

Tags: combinatorics

It is a well known rule, that $\frac{n}{\gcd(n,k)}$ divides $\binom{n}{k}$. Thus, $n$ divides the binomial coefficient if $\gcd(n,k) = 1$.
But, what about the case: $n = 12$ and $k=6$? $12$ divides $\binom{12}{6} = 924$ even though $\gcd(12,6) = 6\neq 1$. What is the simple explanation to this "exception"?

Comment: "if" is not "only if".

Comment: Related: [When is $\binom{2n}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{2n}$ an integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700613/when-is-binom2nn-cdot-frac12n-an-integer).